# List manipulation in python

Tags: python

You have given a list. Length of list can vary.

```
As an example:
1. ll = [1,2,3]
2. ll = [1,2,3,4]
3. ll = [1,2] 
4. ll = []
```

I want to store value in three variables,

```
var1,var2,var3 = None,None,None

If ll[0] exists then var1 = ll[0]
If ll[1] exists then var2 = ll[1]
If ll[3] exists then var3 = ll[2]
```

I have written the solution but it contains if else. Code I have written:-

```
var1,var2,var3 = None,None,None
if len(ll) == 1: 
    var1,var2,var3 = ll[0],None,None
elif len(ll) == 2: 
    var1,var2,var3 = ll[0],ll[1],None
else:
    var1,var2,var3 = ll[0],ll[1],ll[2]
```

#### Is there any good method to solve this without using IF/Else.

Comment: "`If ll[3] exists then var3 = ll[2]`" Is this deliberate or a typo?

Comment: Length of list can vary, but var1,var2,var3 only three variables are to be initialised?

Comment: @Anurag : what's your real use case ?

Comment: @Bruno, Want to extract only first three values from list. And storing  it to database.

Comment: @Anurag: do you really think you need to bind these three values to local vars to "store them to database" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the simplest one

```
var1, var2, var3 = (ll + [None] * 3)[:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking:

```
ll = [1,2,3]
var1, var2, var3 = (ll + [None]*len(ll))[:3]
print var1
# 1
print var2
# 2
print var3
# 3
ll = [1,2]
var1, var2, var3 = (ll + [None]*len(ll))[:3]
print var1
# 1
print var2
# 2
print var3
# None
```

The `ll + [None]*len(ll)` adds (or removes) to the current list by adding `[None, etc]`. The amount of `None`s depends on the length of the list.

So for example, if the list was `[1]`, it would add `[None, None]` to that list, therefore the unpacking wouldn't raise an error as there is the same amount of elements.

You're probably better off using a conditional, maybe something like:

```
if len(ll) > 3:
    var1, var2, var3 = ll[:3]
else:
    var1, var2, var3 = ll + [None] * (3-len(ll))
```

Comment: This will break if len(ll) > 3. You have to use `(ll + [None] * (3-len(ll)))[:3]` instead

Answer (score 1):

I'd go and extend this to allow arbitrary iterables instead of depending on being able to slice, eg:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, islice
a, b, c = islice(chain(your_iterable, repeat(None)), 3)
```

Although, if I didn't want to unpack as such, then I'd look at using a `dict` but this'd have slightly different semantics:

```
var = dict(enumerate(islice(your_iterable, 3), start=1))
var[1] # first item (think of it as `var1`) or
var.get(1) # but get `None` if it wasn't "unpacked"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't encourage this:

```
var1, var2, var3 = ll[:3] + [None] * (3-min(3, len(ll)))
```

Basically it pads the missing values with a list of **None**.

Comment: This doesn't work with the provided examples `2. ll = [1,2,3,4]` causes `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
# You can use other values for this list
default_list = [None] * 3 # Same as None, None, None
var1, var2, var3 = ll[:len(default_list)] + default_list[len(ll):]
```

Basically what it does is create a list the same size of `default_list` filling any missing indexes with the values in `default_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have an itertools based solution so far:

```
import itertools as it
var1, var2, var3 = list(it.chain(ll, it.repeat(None, 3- len(ll))))[:3]
```

But that's just ridiculous

Comment: Posted an `itertools` around the same time... Somewhat different approaches though :)